# Random file-name after ftp upload in delphi

Tags: delphi, file-upload, ftp, indy

I am working an application which needs to upload files to server.
I am using delphi and TIDFtp to upload files.

Everything works ok, except the file name after upload is randomly generated.
The file in my machine is named

> test.txt

and after upload its named in the server like [image: File name in the server after upload.]

How to fix this ?

Here is my code :

```
IdFtp1.Host := 'host';
  IdFtp1.Username := 'uname';
  IdFtp1.Password := 'pass';
  IdFtp1.Connect;
  IdFtp1.Put('test.txt');
  IdFtp1.Disconnect;
```

Comment: Re: Your side question. `AWorkCount` gives you the total # of bytes transferred so far, not the total file size. `OnWorkBegin` gives you `AWorkCountMax`, which is the total size to be uploaded. Using AWorkCount and AWorkCountMax you can calculate the percent done.

Comment: Yeah figured that out! But cannot understand how to fix the first part of the problem!

Comment: What is the server software and OS? There's a reason it's generating a GUID for the filename. Have you contacted the site admin to see why?

Comment: The server is godaddy and the os is windows!

Comment: If you are down-voting, do care to write a reason for that! @who-ever down-voted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indy Put method has a two-argument version

Try this

```
IdFtp1.Put('test.txt', 'remote-file.txt');
```

Comment: You just made my day!!

Comment: @mjn: This two-argument version of `TIdFTP.Put()` (which is actually a 4-argument version with 3 optional parameters) is the same one that Priyabrata was already using. The second parameter is optional. If not specified, the destination filename is extracted from the first argument. There is no possible way the original symptom Priyabrata claimed could ever be happening. For instance, Indy does not generate GUIDs, not even for temp filenames (which `TIdFTP.Put()` does not generate anyway).

Comment: @mjn: The only reasonable conclusion is that either 1) the FTP server is ignoring `TIdFTP`'s specified filename and substituting its own `{guid}.tmp` filename; 2) Priyabrata's FTP client is ignoring the FTP server's specified filename and substituting its own `{guid}.tmp` filename; or 3) this is not Priyabrata's real code, and maybe (s)he is actually using `TIdFTP.StoreUnique()` instead of `TIdFTP.Put()`.